# (Pygame / Python) How do I place an object on my screen based on the middle of its rect?

Tags: python, pygame

I thought I could simply do this:

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=((self.pos_x, self.pos_y)))
```

But that seems to have the same effect as:

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(bottomleft=((self.pos_x, self.pos_y)))
```

What am I missing? Both objects go in as if the (pos_x, pos_y) tuple was describing its lower left corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass arguments to the method `self.image.get_rect()`, it returns a `pygame.Rect` object which has many attributes: `top, bottom, left, right,
topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright, size, width, height, center, centerx, centery, midleft, midright, midtop, midbottom  #(this is from pygame docs)`  which you can use to place your sprite at any position in the screen, for example here you place the sprite just in the middle of the screen:

```
def __init__(self, screen): 
    #Load image
    #...
    self.screen = screen

    self.rect =self.image.get_rect()
    self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

    self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
    self.rect.centery = self.screen_rect.centery
```

I hope that helped.